# kable: obtain from a list of dataframe tables on top of each other instead of next to each other

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

i have a nested list of data.frame that i need to export in html. 
I am using kable and writeLines:

```
kable(list_of_df) %>% writeLines("output.html")
```

Which results in something like this:

```
A   B   C   A   B   C       
1   2   3   x   y   z
4   5   6   x   y   z   
7   8   9   x   y   z
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to automatically place the tables on top of each other instead of next to each other.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand you question correctly - you shouldn't use `kable` to bind data frames stores in a list, try `do.call(rbind, list_of_df)`

Comment: since are df nested in a list your approach does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than I thought

```
map(list_of_df,kable) %>% as.character() %>% writeLines("out.html")
```